# Empty Table with no data display

Tags: iphone

I having problem with my table. After loading everything. My data is being loaded and string into name and loadscore. However it will not show in the table. Please help.

```
static const NSInteger kNameLabelTag = 1337;
static const NSInteger kScoreLabelTag = 5555;

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];


        UILabel *nameLabel = [[UILabel new] autorelease];
        [nameLabel setTag:kNameLabelTag];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:nameLabel];

        UILabel *highscoreLabel = [[UILabel new] autorelease];
        [highscoreLabel setTag:kScoreLabelTag];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:highscoreLabel];

    }
    // Configure the cell.

    //cell.textLabel.text = [loadhighScore objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSDictionary *score = [self.loadhighScore objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *name = [score objectForKey:@"ScoreName"];
    NSString *loadscore = [score objectForKey:@"HighScore"];

    [(UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:kNameLabelTag] setText:name];
    [(UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:kScoreLabelTag] setText:loadscore];




    return cell;
}
```

Comment: consider altering ur initial [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359786/how-do-i-display-the-data-saved-in-table) instead of posting a new on the same topic

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the tableview delegate and datasource connected to your class?

Comment: yes, i have that. the problem i have found out. the main problem is that i do not know how to set the size of the frame

Answer (score 0):

if you are loading in this data after the view has appeared on screen check that you have reloaded the tables data source [yourTableView reloadData];